# WPF InputSimulator not working on a User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, inputsimulator

The goal is to make a User Control Keyboard so I installed InputSimulator from NuGet, I tried it with a button and it's working well of course after setting the property Focusable of that button to False, but when I created a keyboard as a UserControl, the keyboard not working (not typing characters).

Here is the code from the xaml.cs of the User Control:

```
private void clickAlphabet(VirtualKeyCode virtualKey)
    {
        var inputSim = new InputSimulator();
        inputSim.Keyboard.KeyPress(virtualKey);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        clickAlphabet(VirtualKeyCode.VK_A);
    }
```

Xaml of user control(one button):

```
<Button Content="a" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

This code is from App.xaml:

```
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    </Style>
```

Here is how I called the keyboard User Control:

```
<controls:ucKeyboard Margin="7 300"></controls:ucKeyboard>
```

This is the whole xaml of the user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SmartCaisse.PL.UserControls.ucKeyboard"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SmartCaisse.PL.UserControls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="268" d:DesignWidth="797">
<Border CornerRadius="0 0 15 15" Background="green">
    <Grid Width="797">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="7"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="7"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="7"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,7,0"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="60"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="60"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#fff"/>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>


                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="#fff" BorderThickness="2" Focusable="False">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                <Setter Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <Button Content="a" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Button Content="z"/>
            <Button Content="e"/>
            <Button Content="r"/>
            <Button Content="t"/>
            <Button Content="y"/>
            <Button Content="u"/>
            <Button Content="i"/>
            <Button Content="o"/>
            <Button Content="p"/>
            <Button Width="127 ">
                <Image Source="/assets/Icons/VirtualKeyboardIcons/backspace.png" Width="24" Height="24"></Image>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button Content="q"/>
            <Button Content="s"/>
            <Button Content="d"/>
            <Button Content="f"/>
            <Button Content="g"/>
            <Button Content="h"/>
            <Button Content="j"/>
            <Button Content="k"/>
            <Button Content="l"/>
            <Button Content="m"/>
            <Button Content="Entrée" Width="103" Margin="0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="4">
            <Button>
                <Image Source="/assets/Icons/VirtualKeyboardIcons/arrow-up.png" Width="24" Height="24"></Image>
            </Button>
            <Button Content="w"/>
            <Button Content="x"/>
            <Button Content="c"/>
            <Button Content="v"/>
            <Button Content="b"/>
            <Button Content="n"/>
            <Button Content=","/>
            <Button Content="."/>
            <Button Content="-"/>
            <Button Content="_"/>
            <Button>
                <Image Source="/assets/Icons/VirtualKeyboardIcons/arrow-up.png" Width="24" Height="24"></Image>
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
        
        <Border Grid.Row="6" CornerRadius="0 0 15 15">
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="&amp;123" FontSize="18"/>
                <Button Content="@"/>
                <Button Width="529"/>
                <Button>
                    <Image Source="/assets/Icons/VirtualKeyboardIcons/arrow-left.png" Width="24" Height="24"></Image>
                </Button>
                <Button>
                    <Image Source="/assets/Icons/VirtualKeyboardIcons/arrow-right.png" Width="24" Height="24"></Image>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

**Update:** I found that this code (in App.XAML file) doesn't take effect on buttons in the user control:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
</Style>
```

So I rewrite it in the XAML file of the user control, this is not a problem.
The problem is, I found out that if I click on the text of the button (property Content) it work but if I click in the rest space of the button it doesn't work, see this image:
[image]

I found the code that created this problem, this block of code from XAML file of the user control, I added it to remove the default hover effect of buttons:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="#fff" BorderThickness="2" Focusable="False">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
```

So I guess the solution is to find another way to remove the hover effect, any other way to remove it ??

Answer (score 0):

I update your Button Style as below, it can work for click whole button.

```
 <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,7,0"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="60"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="60"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#fff"/>
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>

                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#fff"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
                
            </Style>
```